# Django admin custom form with uploading data

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-import-export

I've a question.
I need to add second functionality to may Django Administration panel:

- I have 2 models (City and Region), one Region has many Cities in it;
- In my admin panel I want to add excel file with cities list when I'm creating new Region

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Город', max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    city_latt = models.CharField('Широта', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    city_long = models.CharField('Долгота', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField('ISO код страны', max_length=5)

   class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Город'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Города'
    
   def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

```
class Canton(models.Model):
    """ Canton list """
    canton_name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=255, blank=False)
    canton_city = models.ManyToManyField(City, verbose_name='Города', blank=False)
    canton_code_for_map = models.CharField('Код для карты', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    canton_shortify = models.CharField('ISO обозначение', max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField('ISO код страны', max_length=5)
    slug = models.SlugField('url', max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.canton_name

    def get_cities(self):
        return ", ".join([c.name for c in self.canton_city.all()])
    get_cities.short_description = "Города"
    get_cities.admin_order_field = 'canton_city'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Территориальные еденицы'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Территориальные еденицы'
```

so how I can create custom form in my admin where I can upload file and than assign specific Region to uploaded cities?

now my admin for Regions looks like this:
**admin.py**

```
class CantonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    canton_city = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.order_by('name'), label='Города')

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = '__all__'

class CantonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
# class CantonAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'canton_name', 'canton_code_for_map', 'canton_shortify', 'slug', 'get_cities', 'country')
    list_filter = ('canton_name', 'country')
    search_fields = ['canton_name__icontains', 'canton_shortify__icontains', 'canton_city__name__icontains', 'country']
    form = CantonForm
    ordering = ['canton_name']

admin.site.register(Canton, CantonAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand exactly what you mean.  Can you provide more detail?  A diagram or annotated screenshot would help.

If you want to have an extra form field in the import screen where you can assign the *same* region to each city in the upload, then this is possible, the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#customize-admin-import-forms) have an example that you can copy.

However, if you want to be able to modify each city in the interface, this would be a lot more difficult.